# How to configure Jmeter test from Azure Release pipeline

Tags: azure, jmeter, azure-devops, load-testing, azure-pipelines

I want to run my Jmeter load test which is available in Azure Test Plan/Load test in Azure Pipeline. My `.jmx` file is located under Test Plan --> Load Test, how can I provide the directory. Please correct be if i'm wrong.

[image]

`.jmx` file located in:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you uploaded the `.jmx` in the "Load test" section it gives your the ability to run the test from there, but if you want to run the tests during the release pipeline you need to include the file in the artifacts and specify the file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @shayki. can you please provide the steps, how to add my .jmx file to artifacts ?  Im new to Devops, feel free to help

Comment: can you please provide me steps to include my .jmx file in the artifacts

Comment: Do you have the .jmx in your repository?

Comment: No I have .jmx file in my local, I dont know how to add it in Artifacts

Comment: In the build pipeline, do you use Hosted agent or Private agent?

Comment: I will be using hosted agent

Comment: So you need to include the .jmx in your repo, then in the build pipeline copy it to the artifacts folder before you publish the artifacts

Comment: You're welcome. if will face in specific issue with how to include the file in the build artifacts you can ask :)